# SQL - Difference between odd/even columns into another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datediff, difference

I have a table which consists of the following data.

```
 Employee      TimeRegister1           TimeRegister2           TimeRegister3           TimeRegister4           
    77    2014-04-01 11:51:43.000 2014-04-01 14:03:52.000 2014-04-01 14:17:01.000 2014-04-01 16:01:12.000
    77    2014-04-03 09:48:33.000 2014-04-03 12:13:43.000 2014-04-03 12:22:27.000 2014-04-03 14:03:43.000
    181   2014-04-02 08:24:34.000 2014-04-02 13:01:10.000 2014-04-02 14:30:31.000 2014-04-02 18:04:04.000
```

What I need is to write, on another column, the total calculated from the differences between each pair of columns (odd minus even) for each employee/day.

In the example above, for `Employee 77 and 2014-04-01`, it should write on another column the sum of the differences between `TimeRegister 2 - TimeRegister 1`, `TimeRegister 4 - TimeRegister 3`.

Something like this should be be output (seconds are irrelevant, just need hours/minutes):

```
 Employee      TimeRegister1           TimeRegister2           TimeRegister3           TimeRegister4              CALCULATEDCOL        
    77      2014-04-01 11:51:43.000 2014-04-01 14:03:52.000 2014-04-01 14:17:01.000 2014-04-01 16:01:12.000    2014-04-01 03:56:00.000
```

Besides the `TimeRegister` Columns can be up to 30 (I just showed 4 columns but could be more) so I need a sequenced calculation for each odd/even pair until it runs out of columns.

Any help how I can achieve this in SQL will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a column which indicates "In" vs "Out" (i.e. currently you assume there are an even number of records and the direction of register). Also, the "DateTime" is really just a time difference, i.e. should be a column with a different data type, like Time?

Comment: Hello Stuart, thanks for your input. Column "TimeRegister1" is the "IN" Column (first time register of the day - always a IN). Sometimes it's possible that there aren't even time register (for instance employee checked in but forgot to check out). This ocorrences should be ignored of course. Let's say an employee checks out at lunch, when he comes back he forgot to check IN. When he checks out at the end of day it would be consider as a CHECK IN. Anomalies will be treated manually (i.e. adding forgotten check in's/out's) and recalculating accordingly.

Comment: That's a really poor table design. It sounds like it's been designed from a physical form rather than by thinking about the data. Ideally, all of these datetime values would be in a single column - with a separate row for each entry. You could approximate this by performing an `UNPIVOT` on this data first.

Comment: Hello Damien, the original table has indeed datetime values in a single column with a separate row for each entry. This is a table resulting from a PIVOT operation. We did this in order to pass it on to a software grid so HR personnel could work with a IN vs OUT in a single row for better analysis. Of course I can work on the original table and then PIVOT all when it haves all the calculations made. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the table presented is correct (i.e. not 30 columns), you can do this by `DATEDIFF`ing the DateTimes, add the differences together, and then adding these back to the base date of one of the times (assuming all DateTimes are on the same day). You can eliminate the seconds by choosing minutes as your diff / add resolution. And to handle missing data, you would require `ISNULL()` or `COALESCE` on each `In / Out` pairing.

```
SELECT Employee, TimeRegister1, TimeRegister2, TimeRegister3, TimeRegister4, 
       DATEADD(mi, ISNULL(DATEDIFF(mi, TimeRegister1, TimeRegister2), 0) 
                 + ISNULL(DATEDIFF(mi, TimeRegister3, TimeRegister4), 0),
               CAST(CAST(TimeRegister1 AS DATE) AS DATETIME)) 
       as CALCULATEDCOL        
FROM TimeRegister;
```

As per the comment, it may be better to split the `CALCULATEDCOL` into separate date and time components, since as it stands,  `CALCULATEDCOL` doesn't represent a point in time at all.

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/28148/1)

If you truly have up to 30 columns, you would need to repeat the calculation for each pair of `In/Out` data (and hope that employees don't leave the building more than 15 times / day!).

**Edit**
To do this from a raw table of clock in / out data, assuming that the direction is obtainable (otherwise the data is next to useless), and discarding any data where the employee hasn't clocked in and out consecutively, on the same day, how about:

```
WITH cte AS 
(
   SELECT Employee, 
          TimeRegister,
          Direction,
          CAST(TimeRegister AS DATE) AS TheDate,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Employee, CAST(TimeRegister AS DATE) 
                             ORDER BY TimeRegister ASC) AS Rnk
   FROM TimeRegister
)
SELECT 
   cur.Employee,
   DATEADD(mi, SUM(DATEDIFF(mi, cur.TimeRegister, nxt.TimeRegister)), 
           CAST(cur.TheDate AS DATETIME)) AS CALCULATEDCOL
   FROM cte cur
      INNER JOIN cte nxt
      ON cur.Employee = nxt.Employee 
         AND cur.TheDate = nxt.TheDate AND cur.Rnk + 1 = nxt.Rnk
   WHERE cur.Direction = 'I' AND nxt.Direction = 'O'
   GROUP BY cur.Employee, cur.TheDate;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d9a7/1)