# SQL - Create row for filling in NULL into missing dates but repeating ID Column Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, row, fill

I have the following tables. One haves the `TimeRegister` for each Employee (each row equals a IN and a OUT in `asc` sequence):

```
Employee         TimeRegister
   15        2014-04-01 11:51:43.000
   15        2014-04-01 14:03:52.000
   15        2014-04-01 14:17:01.000
   15        2014-04-01 16:01:12.000
   15        2014-04-03 09:48:33.000
   15        2014-04-03 12:13:43.000
```

The other table haves all dates:

```
          Date
2014-04-01 00:00:00.000
2014-04-02 00:00:00.000
2014-04-03 00:00:00.000
2014-04-04 00:00:00.000
```

As you can notice on first table there's no record for employee 15 for 2014-04-02. But I wanted that date with a `NULL` Time Register so it appears like this:

```
Employee         TimeRegister
   15        2014-04-01 11:51:43.000
   15        2014-04-01 14:03:52.000
   15        2014-04-01 14:17:01.000
   15        2014-04-01 16:01:12.000
   15                NULL
   15        2014-04-03 09:48:33.000
   15        2014-04-03 12:13:43.000
```

I don't want to `INSERT` into the table itself but rather get this with a `VIEW`.

All the help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello. I tried a simple `LEFT JOIN` with the `Dates` table but it didn't work. Thanks for the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used a recursive cte to generate all dates for a range, but if as you say you have another table with all dates (or all relevant / working dates), use that instead of the `cteDateGen`. Similarly, I've scraped the unique employees from the same table as `TimeRegister` - again you may have another table of Employee. Once you have a list of all dates and employees, you can Left Outer join to the table with `TimeRegister`s to ensure at least one row per Date / Employee combination, even if there is no such row in the table:

```
With cteDateGen AS
(
  SELECT 0 as Offset, CAST(DATEADD(dd, 0, '2014-04-01') AS DATE) AS WorkDate
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT Offset + 1, CAST(DATEADD(dd, Offset, '2014-04-01') AS DATE)
  FROM cteDateGen
  WHERE Offset < 1000
),
cteAllEmployees AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT(Employee) AS Employee
  FROM TimeRegister
)
SELECT d.WorkDate,
       e.Employee, t.TimeRegister
  FROM cteDateGen d
    CROSS JOIN cteAllEmployees e
    LEFT JOIN TimeRegister t
      ON e.Employee = t.Employee AND CAST(t.TimeRegister AS DATE) = d.WorkDate
  WHERE d.WorkDate BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-04-10'
  OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);
```

I'm assuming the same table structure as in the fiddle [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24304613/314291)

Comment: Great stuff! Works perfectly. I just changed `WHERE d.WorkDate BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-04-10'` to `WHERE d.WorkDate >=(SELECT MIN (d.WorkDate) from TimeRegister) AND 'WHERE d.WorkDate <=(SELECT MAX (d.WorkDate) from TimeRegister)` so it gives all relevant dates on the range. Thanks again!. This worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't perfect (it gives the null in the employee rather than the date, and the comparison of just the year/month/day is crude!))

```
select Employee, coalesce(TimeRegister, Date)
from Date
left outer join EmpDate 
  on left(cast(Date as nvarchar), 10) = left(cast(TimeRegister as nvarchar), 10)
```

i.e. gives:

```
EMPLOYEE    COLUMN_1 
15          April, 01 2014 11:51:43+0000
15          April, 01 2014 14:03:52+0000 
15          April, 01 2014 14:17:01+0000
15          April, 01 2014 16:01:12+0000
(null)      April, 02 2014 00:00:00+0000
15          April, 03 2014 09:48:33+0000 
15          April, 03 2014 12:13:43+0000 
(null)      April, 04 2014 00:00:00+0000
```

SQL Fiddle Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/482b1/7/0

Comment: Many thanks for your input although is not exactly what I was looking for but I will keep this code snippet for future implementations. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

DB Design seems a little broken for what you need. This will get you NULL date but also NULL employee.

```
SELECT  T.Employee, T.TimeRegister
FROM    DateTable D
LEFT JOIN   TimeRegisterTable T
        ON  convert(date,T.TimeRegister) = convert(date,D.Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, assuming your first table is called a1 and second is called a2:

```
select a.Employee,b.TimeRegister from a1 a 
    inner join a2 b on a.TimeRegister=b.TimeRegister
union
select x.Employee,null
from a1 x
where x.Employee not in (select d.Employee from a1 d 
    inner join a2 e on d.TimeRegister=e.TimeRegister
    where d.Employee=null)
```

output:

```
15  2014-04-01 11:51:43.000
15  2014-04-01 14:03:52.000
15  2014-04-01 14:17:01.000
15  2014-04-01 16:01:12.000
15  2014-04-03 09:48:33.000
15  2014-04-03 12:13:43.000
15  NULL
```